# export file to excel using treemap

Tags: java, mysql, treemap

Dears
Could you please figure out this code. Actually when I call this method no file is created. IT suppose to export all file from table into excel file, but no error gives with no output as well.

```
 private void writetoExcel() {
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); //Create Blank workbook
        XSSFSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Patients");      //Create a blank spreadsheet with Patients name for spreadsheet

        TreeMap<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();
        data.put("-1", new Object[]{ds.getColumnName(1), ds.getColumnName(2), ds.getColumnName(3), ds.getColumnName(4), ds.getColumnName(5), ds.getColumnName(6), ds.getColumnName(7), ds.getColumnName(8), ds.getColumnName(9)});

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.getRowCount(); i++) {
            data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[]{getCellValue(i, 0), getCellValue(i, 1), getCellValue(i, 2), getCellValue(i, 3), getCellValue(i, 4), getCellValue(i, 5), getCellValue(i, 6), getCellValue(i, 7)});
        }
        Set<String> ids = data.keySet();
        XSSFRow row;
        int rowID = 0;
        for (String key : ids) {
            row = ws.createRow(rowID++);
            Object[] values = data.get(key);
            int cellID = 0;

            for (Object o : values) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellID++);
                cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
            }
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\xampp\\test1.xslx"));
            wb.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


 private String getCellValue(int x, int y) {
        return ds.getValueAt(x, y).toString();

    }
```

I'm calling the method using `writetoExcel();` from the button

Comment: Shouldn't be file in xlsx format rather xslx?

Comment: already changed, but no thing changed